# Javascript: Is it possible to call an object from array by its name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have created an array like this

```
contacts = [bob,ryan,468]
```

Assume that bob and ryan are objects having more than one properties. I know I can call an array by its position, say, `contacts[1]` or `contacts[0]`.

Is it possible to call the bob object by its name? Is there any default method to do this in javascript or should I write my own solution?

**PS: I am totally new to Javascript.**

Comment: You can still access `bob` as long as it's in scope.

Comment: With array - **no**. Use object instead of array

Comment: @Anonymous Platypus What do you mean by name of an object? The variable it's stored in? Please clarify.

Comment: @tim-we I meant the variable that holds the object. Say `bob` in the question. I don't know whether I have a misconception about this as I am new to JS. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to be able to do this:

```
contacts = [bob,ryan,468]
```

`bob` and `ryan` have to be defined somewhere before that line.
Something like this:

```
var bob = {
      name: 'Bob',
      age: 42
    };

var ryan = { name: 'Ryan' };

var contacts = [bob,ryan,468];
```

Instead of using `contacts[0]` and `contacts[1]` you could also just use `bob` and `ryan` to access them.

You are asking for 'call the bob object by its name'. Objects in JavaScript don't have a name. You can have a variable that contains the object (or at least a reference to it) like `var bob = {};`. Or what do you mean by it's name?

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I wanted to call them from array. When I try `console.log(contacts[bob])` it returns `undefined`. I mean by the variable name.

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JS, so all you can do is contacts[0], contacts[1], and so on. You can use plain objects though,have a look at this link: http://www.less-broken.com/blog/2010/12/lightweight-javascript-dictionaries.html

Comment: I hope this comment solved my doubt :) I am accepting this answer. Thank you

Comment: Well thanks for accepting my answer. Were JavaScript Objects (key-value-pairs) the thing you've been looking for?

Comment: Not really. Associative arrays was the one I was looking for. Since it doesn't exist for JS my problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
var as = { "bob": bob, "ryan":ryan, "468":468 };

//as["bob"] -> bob object
```

Comment: This is actually an object, not an associative array. There is no such thing in JS. However this might still be what @Anonymous Platypus was asking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

what you might want here is a hash...

```js
var contacts = {
  first: 'bob',
  last: 'ryan',
  number: 468
};

alert(contacts['last']);
```

Comment: I think u called a property from an object. I am looking to call an object from an array with its variable name. I am not sure whether I went wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function from array prototype to query your array.

```
var vals = [
    {
        "name":"bob",
        "age":50
    },
    {
        "name":"brayan",
        "age":51
    },
    567
];

var query = vals.filter(function(obj){
    if (typeof(obj) === 'object' && 'name' in obj &&     typeof(obj.name) === 'string') {
        if(obj.name === 'bob')
            return true;
    }
    return false;
});

alert(query[0].age);
```

You can modify your query operation with suitable condition.

Here is a [working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0qssp2tk/)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript object we generally keep values in **Key: Value** pairs.

You can use like:

```
var contacts = {"obj_ryan":{"fname":"ryan","lname":"bob","phone":468},
                "obj_mark":{"fname":"mark","lname":"filip","phone":467}
               };

//use them like
alert(contacts.obj_ryan.fname);
alert(contacts.obj_mark.phone);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is just an object rite? Not an array. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, This is an Object. In JS Array is  a type of object only. They both work on concept of Key : Value pair. The difference is only that in objects we explicitly specify both Key and Value(like var x =  {"fname":"mark"}), but in Arrays JS Automatically indexes key with numbers starting with 0( like var x= ["mark"] ). We would access them like x.fname || x["fname"] and x[0]  resp.